# AccessViolation Exception in C# Web API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, access-violation, saprfc

Facing an error while accessing SAP RFC through C# Web API. Here are the details:
I am able to get response from SAP RFC which is stored in out param, but it throws an exception while returning that to my function. Here is the code:

```
    internal string FromBupaToBupaGuid(string sBupa)
    {
        using (SAPContext db = new SAPContext(base.GetConnectStringForRfcUser()))
        {
            ERPConnect.LIC.SetLic(base.GetLicenseKey());
            string sBupaGuid;
            SAPContext.MESSAGESTable mESSAGESTable = new SAPContext.MESSAGESTable();
            sBupa = ToBupa(sBupa);
            db.IST_GET_BPARTNER_GUID(out sBupaGuid, sBupa, mESSAGESTable);

            return sBupaGuid;
        }
    }
```

Here is the exception info:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=ERPConnect40
  StackTrace:
       at ERPConnect.RFCAPI.RfcCallReceiveExt(Int32 handle, Int32 hSpace, String FuncName, StringBuilder Exception)
       at ERPConnect.R3Connection.Ping()
       at ERPConnect.Linq.ERPDataContext.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at ERPConnect.Linq.ERPDataContext.Dispose()
```

**Note:** There is no issue in code, because its quiet old code and was working fine in my earlier machine (Windows 7 + VS 2012), now am having windows 8.1.

I have already tried:

- Check/Uncheck both - Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)
- Visual studio 2012 and 2013 both tried
- .Net framework version 4.5.2

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, issue was related to **librfc32.dll** was missing in **SystemWow** folder, the I got it resolved by putting two librfc dlls: one for 32 bit and the other for 64 bit in **Windows/Systems** folder.

I have referred the below link and it contains required information on library location and dll:

https://my.theobald-software.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/71/9/theobald--products-in-a-64-bit-environment

Hope this helps to others.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue when trying to use standard BAPI function using the connection.CreateFunction() method. It seems to be occurring randomly as well.

```
RFCFunction funcModify = _r3Connection.CreateFunction("BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY");
                funcModify.Exports["NUMBER"].ParamValue = notifNo.PadLeft(12,'0');
```

I have posted a ticket with theobald software, owners of ERPconnect. Will post any useful info if i manage to get to to work.